# how do facebook android sample apps work without debug hash?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-keystore

When I create a facebook app to authenticate android devices, I have to put in a debug hash for testing as well as a hash for my production keystore.

Facebook samples apps on the other hand are intended to work out of the box, this implies that there is a universal android debug hash that exists, or there is an exemption for these apps (based on package name?) on Facebook

insight appreciated, MingLi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal debug hash for Android.

I have not personally tried the sample Facebook apps, but Facebook likely makes an exemption for them on the server side of things by some kind of identifier (package name or some kind of authentication done via code).

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal hash. In order to build and run the samples yourself, you need to add your key hash in your developer settings.

See section 4 of the getting started guide on how to do that (it's towards the bottom of section 4, just before the troubleshooting subsection).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/